# Can RDF be used with JSON in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, json, rdf, marklogic, semantics

As per my knowledge, MarkLogic stores RDF as XMLs.
But what if I need to use RDF in conjunction with JSON documents.
How would I model my JSON documents with RDF? Also if this is possible how do I query JSON and RDF together?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Using RDF in MarkLogic](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/intro#id_81603) section of the Semantic Developer's Guide shows examples of representing triples in JSON. Your document would look like this:

```
{
  "my" : "data",
  "triple" : {
    "subject": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name/John Smith",
    "predicate": "http://example.org/livesIn",
    "object": { "value": "London", "datatype": "xs:string" }
  }
}
```

or like this:

```
{
  "my" : "data",
  "triples" : [{
    "subject": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name/John Smith",
    "predicate": "http://example.org/livesIn",
    "object": { "value": "London", "datatype": "xs:string" }
  },{
    "subject": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name/London",
    "predicate": "http://example.org/isIn",
    "object": { "value": "England", "datatype": "xs:string" }
  },{
    "subject": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name/John Smith",
    "predicate": "http://example.org/livesWith",
    "object": { "value": "Jane Smith", "datatype": "xs:string" }
  }]
}
```

Querying JSON and RDF together is the same as querying XML and RDF together. Take a look at the [Using Semantics with cts Searches](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/semantic-searches#id_92265) section, which shows how to use

- cts:triples
- cts:triple-range-query
- cts:search
- cts:contains

Comment: Thanks..that helped!